# What do I need to shoot sharp high school baseball photographs on a budget?

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation, sports

I need a zoom lens ASAP for high school baseball. (And then hopefully in 2020 college baseball.) This is only to take pictures of my son — for now high school and travel baseball.

I have older Canon Rebel EOS XSI 450D. I think I bought it in 2007/2008.

The lens I have now (which my dad recommended) just doesn’t cut it. 
It is a Canon EF 75-300mm lens (without a stabilizer).

Many of the pictures that I have taken during the day of sports (baseball, lacrosse and soccer) are blurry but usable. But the pictures at night are ALL BLURRY!

And I have tried every setting.

I don’t know if I need to upgrade my camera because it is not  powerful/advanced enough, or what lens would work with the Canon Rebel EOS XSi 450D that I already own?

Maybe price-wise it is better to upgrade to a better camera and lens? But a $1000 lens by itself even refurbished isn’t in the budget.

I don’t know if any of these camera lenses would work. I have read some of them don’t work at night for sports photos.  I am so confused.

- EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS STM lens features the optics, AF and image stabilization.
- Canon - EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 III USM Telephoto Zoom Lens - Multi
- 70-200 f/2.8 (IT IS VERY $$$!)

Or none of the above?

Can anyone recommend any lens that could get me through at least Highschool baseball season? And remember I really cannot use a flash.

Thank you in advance for any advice and suggestions you can provide!

Comment: This is the same question, asked by the same user, that was closed as a duplicate barely a week ago. https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/96252/15871